# Blazor WASP Get pressed key on Mobile (Android)

Tags: c#, web, blazor

Function:
`public async Task CheckAnswer(KeyboardEventArgs key)`
is not returning any `key.code` on mobile, on PC it returns, for example: "KeyA".

Am I missing sometihng obvious?

Comment: Did you find an answer with this?

Comment: No... ended up making a crappy workaround

Comment: Please share if you can here.

Comment: I'm with this issue too, using android it returns empty or "Undefined" for all KeyboardEventArgs